# Regex w/grep against tnsnames.ora

Tags: regex, unix, grep, sh, tns

I am trying to print out the contents of a TNS entry from the tnsnames.ora file to make sure it is correct from an Oracle RAC environment.

So if I do something like:

```
grep -A 4 "mydb.mydomain.com" $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
```

I will get back:

```
mydb.mydomain.com =
(DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS =
  (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost.mydomain.com)(PORT = 1521))
  (CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=mydb)))
```

Which is what I want.  Now I have an environment variable being set for the JDBC connection string by an external program when the shell script gets called like:

```
export $DB_URL=@myhost.mydomain.com:1521/mydb
```

So I need to get TNS alias mydb.mydomain.com out of the above string.  I'm not sure how to do multiple matches and reorder the matches with regex and need some help.

```
grep @.+: $DB_URL
```

I assume will get the

```
@myhost.mydomain.com:
```

but I'm looking for

```
mydb.mydomain.com
```

So I'm stuck at this part.  How do I get the TNS alias and then pipe/combine it with the initial grep to display the text for the TNS entry?

Thanks

---

update:

@mklement0 @Walter A - I tried your ways but they are not exactly what I was looking for.

```
echo "@myhost.mydomain.com:1521/mydb" | grep -Po "@\K[^:]*"
echo "@myhost.mydomain.com:1521/mydb" | sed 's/.*@\(.*\):.*/\1/'
echo "@myhost.mydomain.com:1521/mydb" | cut -d"@" -f2 | cut -d":" -f1
echo "@myhost.mydomain.com:1521/mydb" | tr "@:" "\t" | cut -f2
echo "@myhost.mydomain.com:1521/mydb" | awk -F'[@:]' '{ print $2 }'
```

All these methods get me back: myhost.mydomain.com

What I am looking for is actually: mydb.mydomain.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Note:

- For brevity, the commands below use `bash`/`ksh`/`zsh` [here-string](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument?action=show&redirect=HereString) syntax to send strings to stdin (`<<<"$var"`). If your shell doesn't support this, use `printf %s "$var" | ...` instead.</sup>

The following `awk` command will extract the desired string (`mydb.mydomain.com`) from `$DB_URL` (`@myhost.mydomain.com:1521/mydb`):

```
awk -F '[@:/]' '{ sub("^[^.]+", "", $2); print $4 $2 }'  <<<"$DB_URL"
```

- `-F'[@:/]'` tells `awk` to split the input into fields by either `@` or `:` or `/`. With your input, this means that the field of interest are *part* of the *second* field (`$2`) and the fourth field (`$4`). The `sub()` call removes the first `.`-based component from `$2`, and the `print` call pieces together the result.

To put it all together:

```
domain=$(awk -F '[@:/]' '{ sub("^[^.]+", "", $2); print $4 $2 }'  <<<"$DB_URL")
grep -F -A 4 "$domain" "$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora"
```

You don't strictly need intermediate variable `$domain`, but I've added it for clarity.
Note how `-F` was added to `grep` to specify that the search term should be treated as a *literal*, so that characters such as `.` aren't treated as regex metacharacters.

Alternatively, for more robust matching, use a *regex* that is anchored to the start of the line with `^`, and `\`-*escape* the `.` chars (using shell [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)) to ensure their treatment as literals:

```
grep -A 4 "^${domain//./\.}" "$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora"
```

Comment: Okay I saw your recent update...it seems to be working now as intended.  Thanks!

Comment: @dave111: Glad to hear it. Your question was well presented to begin with, but, as you can see, the similarity between `mydb` and `myhost` caused both me and Walter A to miss the difference. Note to self: read more carefully. Suggestion for you: perhaps explicitly highlight things people may overlook in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a part of a string with

```
# Only GNU-grep
echo "@myhost.mydomain.com:1521/mydb" | grep -Po "@\K[^:]*"
# or
echo "@myhost.mydomain.com:1521/mydb" | sed 's/.*@\(.*\):.*/\1/'
# or
echo "@myhost.mydomain.com:1521/mydb" | cut -d"@" -f2 | cut -d":" -f1
# or, when the string already is in a var
echo "${DB_URL#*@}" | cut -d":" -f1
# or using a temp var
tmpvar="${DB_URL#*@}"
echo "${tmpvar%:*}"
```

I had skipped the alternative awk, that was given by @mklement0 already:

```
echo "@myhost.mydomain.com:1521/mydb" | awk -F'[@:]' '{ print $2 }'
```

The awk solution is straight-forward, when you want to use the same approach without awk you can do something like

```
echo "@myhost.mydomain.com:1521/mydb" | tr "@:" "\t" | cut -f2
```

or the ugly

```
echo "@myhost.mydomain.com:1521/mydb" | (IFS='@:' read -r _ url _; echo "$url")
```

What is happening here?
After introducing the new IFS I want to take the second word of the input. The first and third word(s) are caught in the dummy var's `_` (you could have named them `dummyvar1` and `dummyvar2`). The pipe `|` creates a subprocess, so you need `()`to hold reading and displaying the var `url` in the same process.

Comment: ++ for showing so many options, but you may as well throw in the `awk -F'[@:]' '{ print $2 }'` too.

Comment: Turns out we both initially missed that the OP didn't just want a straight substring extraction, but wanted `myhost` replaced with `mydb` from the _end_ of the input string in the extracted string.

Comment: Since the awk already solved it, I will leave a solution with `sed` or `IFS='@:.'` as a practice for the user..